# Where would I start if I want to create my own text editor on the UWP platform?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Where would I start if I want to create my own text editor on the UWP platform?
The TextBox and RichEditBox have many limitations that hinder my requirements for a text control, and so I would like to create my own. I know it will be a long tedious process, but I don't mind putting in the work. I just don't even know what APIs to begin with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you start by looking at source code that others have written.  You can download the following projects from [GitHub](https://github.com/):

1. [10Develops/textie](https://github.com/10Develops/textie)
2. [ph1ll/UwpEdit](https://github.com/ph1ll/UwpEdit)
3. [jan-patrick/ScriptText](https://github.com/jan-patrick/ScriptText)
4. [UWP-Open-Source-Community/Atom](https://github.com/UWP-Open-Source-Community/Atom)
5. [springcomp/TextPad](https://github.com/springcomp/TextPad)
6. [karan-randhawa/Notepad-Sharp](https://github.com/karan-randhawa/Notepad-Sharp)
7. [ph1ll/UwpEdit](https://github.com/ph1ll/UwpEdit)

Besides reading the code and running in the Debugger, I would also suggest looking at the Commit history for these apps on GitHub, to see what problems the developers struggled with.